# Changing label color for Flex 4 FormItems

Tags: flex4, flex-spark

Wonder if there is a way to change color for a label in Spark FormItem component. I tried this:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

s|FormItem s|Label#labelDisplay {
   color: #333333;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 30;
}
```

and all of the styles work great, **except** the font color, which stays black for some reason. I would greatly appreciate any help resolving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer from Peter DeHaan on my question "Do we need the equivalent of "labelStyleName" property for Spark FormItem class?" http://forums.adobe.com/thread/759374?tstart=0  
  
"Because the color and fontWeight are declared in the default Spark FormItem skin, I believe you will have to create a custom skin if you want to override those styles."